# How do I use a CSS attribute's value of an html element as input when submiting a form with Django?

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms

Please first click the link to the image below to understand my question/situation.

If the text below a particular species icon (circle with animal image inside it) is bold, I would like that to be used as input criteria for getting information from a database. In other words, I want to use the font-weight CSS property of a "< p >" element as an input. Only one "species text" can be bold at a time.

For example, if I have "D. rerio" selected (its font is bold) and I click the "search" button, I would like for the back-end to know that it needs to pull information from the "D. rerio" database specifically.

[image]

Comment: First explain how you are creating those icons in HTML and how they are being switched to "selected".

Comment: The icon itself is just a .png image with transparency enabled. I'm using a jQuery hover event that causes the icon to receive a glow when the user hovers their cursor over it. And once they click the icon, the text below it turns bold using the jQuery click event like so: $("#fishIcon").click(function(){$("#fishIconText").css("font-weight", "700")});

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to send the value of the CSS, you should use the same process that sets the CSS to set a value in a hidden field. Something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="species" id="id_species">
...
$("#fishIcon").click(function(){
    $("#fishIconText").css("font-weight", "700")
    $('#id_species').val('fish')
});
```

Comment: That's a pretty clever work-around to the lack of the kind of input type I was looking for. Thank you very much!